# Python сканирование текста с изображения

Tags: python

Сидел я на Kwork и поступил запрос на создание бота для ВК , который будет делать авто-рекламу внутри паблика .

Чувак объяснил , как должен работать бот :

1) Человек пишет боту о том , что хочет рекламу в паблике и скидывает изображение , которое должно быть в рекламном посте

2) Бот должен отсканировать картинку на наличие - "Запрещённых слов" и скинуть реквизиты

3) После оплаты бот выкладывает это изображение в случае , если все нормально .

Но я не понимаю , как бот должен отсканировать изображение на текст ?
Как это вообще возможно сделать , не скачивая самого изображения ?

Comment: не скачивая - никак, да и скачав, если текст будет корявый - шансов мало, а так это работа отдельных библиотек

Comment: тебе нужна нейросеть способная анализировать картинки.

Comment: Что значит "отсканировать картинку", если это не должно включать себя скачивание изображения? Бот по любому должен как-то эту картинку получить. Телепатически сканировать изображение компьютеры пока не умеют.

Answer (score 3):

Tesseract OCR хорошо распознает. Если ему предавать хорошо обработанное изображения для распознания. Лично я смог для своего проекта добиться от него 99% распознания текста.

А для вашей ситуации, опишите функцию, если поступил запрос боту на рекламу пусть выполняет скрипт, как открыть изображения не качая его, это просто.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

url = "http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/02/mem/muzhik-bleat_43233947_orig_.jpg"

image = Image.open(urlopen(url))
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text =  pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='rus')
print(text)
```